# Displaying individual data from a count query(mySQL/php)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database called 'Telcel' and a table called 'calls'
columns in my table are id,call_from,call_to,date_time,duration,network,cost,status

I have the following code:

```
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "daven", "H3x^g0n", "Telcel");
        $query = "SELECT id, COUNT(id), call_from,ROUND(SUM(cost), 2) FROM calls GROUP BY call_from ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="total.php">'. $row['call_from'] .'</a></td>
                        <td>'. $row['COUNT(id)'] .'</td>
                        <td>'. $row['ROUND(SUM(cost), 2)'] .'</td>
                    </tr>
                 ';
        }
```

which returns for example:

```
Call From   Calls   Cost
Shannon     10      50.2
Tom         3       7.6
```

I'd like when a name is selected to display all the calls, duration for each call and cost of each call made by the selected caller on the next page,So if Tom is selected display all the relevant information for Tom only, and if Shannon is selected same thing etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sent GET requrest with url like `total.php?call_from=Tom`
So, you need to generate a href link with call from name :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    <td><a href="total.php?call_from='.$row["call_from"].'">'. $row['call_from'] .'</a></td>
    ...
}
```

And `total.php` use `$_GET["call_from"]` for receiving id from url to use in query  :

```
$call_from = $_GET["call_from"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM calls WHERE call_from = ". $call_from;
... //Display the table
```

Hope this help :)